# Raphaël JS paper.getById() returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm trying to get the Raphaël object by using the getById() function, however no matter what I try the function returns null.

Here is the Raphaël JS code I'm working with:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 100);
circle.attr({"fill": "#f00", "id": "test"});
circle.data("id", "test");

var getCircle = paper.getById("test");

alert(getCircle); //Returns null?
```

Why doesn't `paper.getById("test");` return the circle object?

I've defined the ID by both using `attr()` and `data()` yet nothing seems to work.

JsFiddle of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/Mf9q6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.getById) carefully:

> Returns you element by its *internal* ID.

This is not the same as the `id` attribute on the element. The id expected by `Paper.getById()` is [`Element.id`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.id)

You probably want `var getCircle = paper.getById(circle.id);` which is just a reference to the same object as `circle` anyway.

[Here's your fiddle, updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Mf9q6/1/).

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing this now.  I was hoping that I could access the objects through defined IDs.  Oh well, I'll find another solution to the initial problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to set `id` to your element. Then somewhere down the line get the element's id.

If it is the case then you are almost there:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 100);
circle.attr({"fill": "#f00", "id": "test"});
circle.data("id", "test");

var getCircle = circle.data("id");

alert(getCircle); //Returns test
```

**EDIT**

If you are trying to get the circle by the value, like in your example "test"

```
paper.forEach(function (el) 
{
    if (el.data("id") == "test")
        // return el - do what you want
});
```

Comment: No, I was attempting to retrieve a Rapheal object using a specified ID.  I know you can set object data, but retrieving an object based on that data's value is really what the question is.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I decided to go with a array/key mapping solution for performance reasons.  I didn't want to have to loop through my entire paper set to find a single object (as I have a ton of objects and it would take a performance hit).  Mapping the objects to specific keys in an array seemed to be the best fit for my situation.  `paperObjects['test'] //returns the test object`